# Vimium interfering with HTML after removal

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, vimium

Until last week I had the [Vimium extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) installed in my copy of Google Chrome. Vimium inserts some HTML and JS into pages I view to work. I've never had any troubles with this up until recently.

I run a Django development server for my job and on a certain page that's served by it a  was wrapped inside a  with the classes 'vimiumReset' and 'vimiumHUD'. This  has style attribute with the value 'display:none;', thus my form never shows up.

After trying some things I decided to uninstall Vimium. I did this the usual way using the Chrome settings menu. However, the Vimium div keeps appearing in my HTML.

The strange thing is that it does not appear in my page source so some relic of my Vimium installation appears to keep altering the HTML I see in my browser. The even stranger thing is that in other browsers (Firefox and Safari) this div is also inserted, but does **not** appear in the page source. The *even* stranger thing is that this div also shows up on other devices that try to view this page over LAN.

When someone runs the same project in their own development server the  does not show up, so it's not hidden somewhere in the project code.

So in short:

- Removed Vimium from Chrome
- Vimium inserted HTML keeps showing up in viewed pages
- Vimium inserted HTML does not appear in page source
- Viewing the page on other devices on the network also shows the Vimium inserted HTML, even though Vimium has never been installed on those devices.

Any ideas where this problem originates from?